# Android Studio 1.5 cannot find android.view.View (automatically)

Tags: android, view

Is anyone else with Android studio 1.5 having issues where when you add a View object to your class it isn't automatically resolving the class and finding android.view.View.

Even if I try and use the shortcut for it to find the import class it fails and I have to manually type it in every time.

I am wondering is this a local issue to my machine or are others seeing it as well and I should submit the bug report.

Comment: Did you try Ctr + Space?

Comment: Sounds like a library specific issue to me. Are you using any library?

Comment: I am using several but in previous test projects I wasn't and had the same issue the only constant was the appcompat libs.

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had somehow used the exclude dropdown box and so when I checked the auto import there was an exclusion for android.view

Answer (score 0):

You can go to

> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> check Add
>   unambiguous imports on the fly

with that setting Android studio will automatically import it for you

Comment: I already have that setting set which is why this flagged as odd to me, most of everything comes up easily its just the android.view.View and android.view.LayoutInflater that continually have to be manually typed in.